# Windows 10 unexpected kernal mode trap bsod debugging

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

So I'm running Windows 10 dual boot with Manjaro on an HP Probook G1 650, and for the longest time, I've been having a reoccurring blue screen of death. I've done some debugging myself, but I'm stuck and don't know what else to try.

It's always an "unexpected kernel mode trap error", and it specifies which driver goes wrong. For the most part, it's netwbw02.sys that fails, but on occasion, it will loop bsod w/o booting and a different driver, ndis.sys or wpprecorder.sys is cited. The bsod appears just a few minutes after booting, even when I just leave it running.

I have tried disk check, memory check, system file checker, all of which returned nothing found. My windows is updated to the most recent version, and I've gone through and made sure each driver has been updated. Additionally, in safe mode, the blue screen only occurs in safe mode w/ networking, and even then only when I connect to wifi.

Any help would be appreciated. thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

ndis.sys is a network driver, so maybe a service that uses it doesn't start when it should, or stops right after starting and causes the BSODs. wpprecorder.sys is in charge of checking for habitual WiFi networks SSIDs, and to connect to them in order of preference, more often than not automatically, if you checked that box on first connection.

If both those drivers don't load in memory as they should, you're likely to experience connection issues, but not necessarily a BSOD, though.

Can you check in your services.msc if WLAN auto config service is set to full automatic (not delayed start)? If not, set it so and see how it goes.

Comment: it is set to fully automatic. is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Which bootloader are you using? Did you install Manjaro after Windows, or the other way around? That's important, because I had the same issue, more or less, years ago after installing Ubuntu in dual-boot alongside Win7 on an old laptop: no BSODs in my case, but no WiFi. Turned out, GRUB would cut power on the WiFi chip prior to boot, for some reason I never could fathom, and I opted for Win7 at boot, I had no connectivity. I had to remove Ubuntu and repair MBR to get it back. I believe there are still notes about that in the Ubuntu forums somewhere, though I couldn't find any just now.

Comment: im using grub. i installed manjaro after windows. What would i have to search for to find those notes?

Comment: I suppose you can try on the Ubuntu forums here and there, but before that, have you tried an "sfc /scannow" in elevated command line? If some system files, probably drivers, are corrupted somehow, Windows will replace them from its secure repository on your system drive. It's been known to work rather well for such issues.

Comment: i mentioned i ran system filer checker in an admin cmd - it came back with nothing though. idk what u mean by elevated but i assume you mean admin

Comment: Yes, I meant admin. Did you also run a "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" (no quotes, of course), either from an elevated PowerShell window or via command line?

Comment: I just ran it and it gave me the following: "Error 0x800f081f the source files could not be found. Use the source option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. I've looked it up and I think just reinstalling windows is the move?

Comment: Do you have a Windows ISO handy? If not, download one from Microsoft's website (it's free), or use this freeware called Windows-ISO-Downloader (here: https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool), save the ISO somewhere, mount it (Windows Explorer can do that for you, but if you have another program in mind, use it), then locate the install.wim file, and use this command (admin):  "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess" after replacing D:\ with the actual letter of your ISO.

Comment: I did everything, but it still gave me the source files could not be found. is it ok if i do this in safe mode? or should i be trying to do this in normal windows?

Comment: Safe mode won't change anything if the source can't be found by DISM. You can try to copy the "install.wim" file from the ISO onto, say, your Desktop, and try DISM again, this time from the PowerShell console (admin) instead of command line.

Comment: I've tried every variation of this. With powershell/cmd & copying to desktop as well as extracting the right iso(w10 pro) and specifying that as the source, but it still gives me source file not found.

Comment: You can try all the commands listed on this page (https://www.wintips.org/fix-dism-source-files-could-not-be-found-windows-10-8/) in sequence, but it seems that the source you used is different from the version of Windows you have installed on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap Windows 10: Why It Occurs?
Well, the main reason for this error comes when you connect new hardware or there is faulty RAM is in your PC. There are several reasons for its occurrence mentioned below:-

Faulty Driver

Memory Caching

Viruses

These are the reasons for its occurrence. Now let’s fix this issue.

Solutions are given below:-

1. Check or remove your new hardware.
2. Use the windows diagnostic memory tool (just type in the search bar windows memory diagnostic and run it).
3. Update your windows to their latest version.
4. Reset your PC
5. [Use BSOD troubleshooter](https://yourwindowshelper.com/unexpected-kernel-mode-trap-windows-10/).
6. Run SFC scan (in command prompt type Sfc/scannow.
7. Run Dism command.
8. Run Chkdsk.
9. Update drivers.
10. Reinstall your drivers.

These are the solutions you can try.